# SQL Query Incorrect syntax near @parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Declare @motherTongue varchar(20) = 'Doesn''t Matter' 

if (@motherTongue = 'Doesn''t Matter') 
begin
    @motherTongue = null 
end
```

I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@motherTongue' error

I am just a beginner.

Comment: Pretty sure that second @ shouldn't be there.

Comment: yes the red underline of syntax error is shown on second one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SET/Select` to assign value to a variable

```
if(@motherTongue = 'Doesn''t Matter') 
Begin 
SET @motherTongue = null  --Here 
End
```

But I will do this using `CASE` instead of `IF`

```
SET @motherTongue = case when @motherTongue = 'Doesn''t Matter' then NULL END
```

You can use `NULLIF` as well

```
SET @motherTongue = NULLIF(@motherTongue,'Doesn''t Matter')
```